# input filtering in CCK fields,how is it possible?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, cck

i have added to new fields using CCK to my custom content type. there are email and phone number and i want to restrict their input to just numbers for phone number field and special pattern to email field.

how can i do that?

thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

There are specific CCK field types for phone number and specific CCK field types for email. You should use these instead of CCK text fields as they automatically validate/restrict the input.